# am I implementing the javascript wrong?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so I'm doing this navbar that will highlight a button depending on the section the user is currently on, whenever I re-save the file without even changing anything it will work correctly, highlighting with the color on click or scroll when the section is changed.

when it does work, it only takes to charge the page again and stops working, am I implementing the javascript wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import FrontPage from './Routes/FrontPage'
import Products from './Routes/Products'
import Clients from './Routes/Clients'
import Contact from './Routes/Contact'
import {BsLinkedin} from 'react-icons/bs'
import {GrInstagram} from 'react-icons/gr'




function App() {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll("nav .container ul li");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});

  return (
    <>
    <nav>
      <div className="container">
        <ul>
          <li><img src='https://diagnosemlpdf.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/landing/static+source/logos/myfutureai_blanco_logo.png' style={{width:"80%",  padding:"0" , margin:"0"}}/></li>
          <li class="Inicio active"><a href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="Productos"><a href="#Productos">Productos</a></li>
          <li class="Clientes"><a href="#Clientes">Clientes</a></li>
          <li class="Contacto"><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
          <li style={{"position":"relative", "top":"2vw"}}><a href='https://www.linkedin.com/company/myfutureai/'><BsLinkedin/></a></li>
          <div className='aristas'>
          <li><a href='https://www.instagram.com/myfuture_ai/'><GrInstagram/></a></li>
          <li><a href='https://twitter.com/myfuture_ai'><img style={{"width": "100%", "margin":"0", "padding":"0"}} src='/twitter.png'/></a></li>
          </div> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section id="Inicio">

        <FrontPage/>
      </section><section id="Productos">
        <Products/>
      </section><section id="Clientes">
        <Clients/>
      </section><section id="Contacto">
        <Contact/>
      </section>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*****CSS*****__

```
/* _____NAVBAR CSS_______ */
nav {
  width: 10vw;
  height:100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
nav .container {
  width: 10vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;

}
nav .container ul  {
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000040;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
nav .container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav .container ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav .container ul li.active {
  background-color: #5e17eb;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}
nav .container ul li.active a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back with the answer... even though the javascript logic was okay, the easiest way to approach this problem in react js was using REACT ROUTER V5( specifically  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0")  --- ***you will have problems with v6***--- and it's complement to link sections from the same page REACT ROUTER HASHLINK. this was way easier and the styling was in a CSS file here is the code:

the ids that links the hash code to the section are inside each component's file

```
import React from "react";
import FrontPage from './Routes/FrontPage'
import Products from './Routes/Products'
import Clients from './Routes/Clients'
import Contact from './Routes/Contact'
import { NavHashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";

  function App() {




    
    return (
      <><nav>
        <Link  to='#home' smooth>Inicio</Link>
        <Link  to='#about' smooth>Productos</Link>
        <Link  to='#clients' smooth>Clientes</Link>
        <Link  to='#contact' smooth>Contacto</Link>
      </nav>
      <section>
          <FrontPage />
          </section>
          <section>
          <Products />
          </section>
          <section>
          <Clients />
          </section>
          <Contact />
        </>
     )
  }
  
  export default App;
```

in the css  portion the haslink can be styled using "a" as a reference.
CSS

```
a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 15px;
 
 
}
a.active {
 width: 90%;
 color:#5e17eb;
 border-right: 4px solid white;
 transition:400ms ease-in ;
}
```